# apk expansion download failed because you may not have purchased this app

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

Dears,

reference to my old post, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48470278/app-expansion-download-not-working). I am trying to download apk-expansion. I managed to finsih the code and test it, and it's working 100% correctly. my problem is that when trying to generate signed apk, the download is not working
below you will find the log.
your suggestions please.

```
510 18311-18350/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[LVLDownloadService]
                                               Process: com.MyPkage_name, PID: 18311
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Package.getName()' on a null object reference
                                                   at bcj.a(SourceFile:484)
                                                   at bcj.a(SourceFile:499)
                                                   at com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader.impl.DownloaderService.a(SourceFile:1038)
                                                   at bbu.handleMessage(SourceFile:108)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: This answer solved my problem :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48396781/applicensing-fails-signature-is-empty-string

Answer (score 0):

You can only download Expansion files when the Play store knows the user has installed the app from Play (for paid or free apps). If you publish the app to play as an Alpha version then expansion files will work.

Comment: Hi Nick, could you please check. I got new error ( only when trying signed apk)

Comment: Stack overflow is not the place for tech support. It is a place for answering technical questions which are useful to everyone. If you need a specific question about your app answering you should contact Google Play developer support via the Play console.